# Print portion of a file between two "headers"

Tags: bash, sed

I feel as if this question must have been asked before, but I simply cannot find a similar question.

I have a very simple file format:

```
Header 1:
    <multiline text>
Header 2:
    <multiline text>
Header 3:
    <multiline text>
```

where the (arbitrarily-named) headers each end with a colon, followed by text that is indented with spaces.

I'd like to, for example, pick out the text under a particular header, e.g. "Header 2". The most obvious thing to try is `grep`, but I can only match certain lines and output a fixed number of context lines with that. I also looked at using `sed`, like so:

```
sed -ne '/Header 2:/,$p'
```

but of course this prints out everything up to the end of the file.

EDIT: In an actual use-case, I won't necessarily know what header follows "Header 2", if there even is one (it could be the last one in the file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '!/^ /&&/:$/{p=0}p;/^Header 2:$/{p=1}' file
```

How does it work:

- This block `!/^ /&&/:$/{p=0}` means:  If you find a line that does not begin with a space and ends with a colon ":", then set the flag `p` to zero
- This block `p;` means: if the flag has a non-zero value, then print the current line
- This block `/^Header 2:$/{p=1}` means: If you find a line that matches `Header 2`, then set the flag  `p` to `1`.

This works, because variables that are not initialized have a zero value.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned the header after `Header 2` might be indeterminate or nonexistent. So I cannot rely on its value.

Comment: @nneonneo So how will you know when the block has ended?

Comment: Each header is unindented and ends with a colon, and it could also be ended by EOF.

Comment: Nice, it worked! How does this actually work? I'm totally unfamiliar with `awk` beyond simple stuff like `{ print $2 }`.

Comment: @nneonneo Added explanation. Let me know if it is not clear enough

Comment: Thank you very much. This was quite helpful!

Comment: IMHO `!/^ /&&/:$/{p=0}` would be clearer written `/^[^ ].*:$/{p=0}`.

Comment: @EdMorton I guess it depends if you prefer reading regex or boolean conditions. Personally I find the first one more readable, but complex regexes make me dizzy

Comment: Mostly I just find `starts with a non-blank` easier to understand than `not starts with a blank` and I like the `.*` to highlight/clarify the sequence of the RE segments - when I see `RE && RE` I usually think it's being used because the 2 REs can occur in any order, which isn't the case here (yes, I know the second one ends in `$` so it's not hard to figure out). nbd either way though.

Answer (score 2):

Or with `sed`

```
sed -n '/Header 2:/,/Header/{/Header/!p}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'f&&/^ /{print; next} {f=/^Header 2:/}' file
```